# VBA - Issue with graph saving as PDF

Tags: vba, pdf, graph

I have an issue with my code, to give you a bit of context, I have a macro that is saving a specific print area as PDF. In this print area there is a graph. When I am asking to print, the graph show up, however, when I am using my macro, the graph doesn't show up in the PDF, but when printing, this PDF, the graph show up. This is my code:

```
Sub SaveActiveSheetAsPDFIn2016()
    'Antoine Hervieux : 5-April-2016
    'Test macro to save as pdf with ExportAsFixedFormat
    Dim FileName As String
    Dim FolderName As String
    Dim Folderstring As String
    Dim FilePathName As String

    Sheets("Summary").PageSetup.Orientation = xlLandscape

    'Name of the folder in the Office folder
    FolderName = "PDFFolder"
    'Name of the pdf file
    FileName = Sheets("Summary").Range("C4") & ".pdf"

    Folderstring = CreateFolderinMacOffice2016(NameFolder:=FolderName)
    FilePathName = Folderstring & Application.PathSeparator & FileName
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("chart 1").PrintObject = True

    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, FileName:= _
    FilePathName, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
    IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False

    MsgBox "You find the PDF file in this location : " & FilePathName
End Sub
```

Do you have any idea why the graph is not showing up? BTW I am on MAC.
Thanks a lot

Comment: Try using the [same method on only the chart](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.chart.exportasfixedformat.aspx) and see what happens.  Also, what happens if you try a different export format, such as `XPS`?